# Initialize class type with a protocol initializer

Tags: swift, generics

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

public protocol Initializer {
    init(id: String)
}

public class A: UIView, Initializer {
    public required init(id: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class C {
    public static func someFunc<T>(myClass: T.Type) -> T where T: Initializer {
        return myClass.init(id: "test")
    }
}

let myType: UIView.Type = A.self
let myType2: Initializer.Type = A.self

let myView = C.someFunc(myClass: myType)
let myView2 = C.someFunc(myClass: myType2)

let myView3 = C.someFunc(myClass: myType as! Initializer.Type)
let myView4 = C.someFunc(myClass: myType2 as! UIView.Type)
```

I get errors on all my attempts to call `C.someFunc` function. This is what I want and expect:

I get an array of class types which conforms to the `Initializer` protocol and are inherted from `UIView`. I then want to call the `someFunc` method to call the initializer for me and dynamically choose the class for me, and returns an UIView. Can I say something to the compiler like: 'This is a class which inherts from `UIView` and conforms to protocol `Initializable`'?

Edit:

Well some calls to function `someFunc` works when I cast alot:

```
class C {
    public static func someFunc<T>(myClass: T.Type) -> T where T: UIView {
        return (myClass as! Initializer.Type).init(id: "test") as! T
    }
}
```

But isn't there a compile error checker with type constrains available?

Edit 2:

Strangest of all, this is not working:

```
class C {
    public static func someFunc<T>(myClass: T.Type) -> T where T: Initializer, T: UIView {
        return myClass.init(id: "test") // error
    }
}
```

error:

> Argument labels '(id:)' do not match any available overloads

Why does this error occured? Type T has to conform to protocol Initializable which means it should have an public initializer with signature id: String.

Comment: The problem here is that you're losing static typing. If you give `myType2: Initializer.Type` as a parameter to the function, what will the return type be? What's the type of `myView3` supposed to be? How is the compiler to know?

Comment: @Alexander See my edit (edit 2 actually). Type T has to be 1. an UIView, 2. has to conform to Initializable. Why can't I call the initializer?

Comment: Oh, now that I look at it again, I think this is one of those "protocols don't conform to themselves" situations (google that quote)